# How to get checked values of a Extjs 4 radio group?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have bottom bar added to a panel like this

```
bbar: [{
        xtype       : 'button',
        text        : 'Select Filter By',
        itemId      : 'filter_by',  
        arrowAlign  : 'right',  
        menu        : [{
                        text    : 'Item Code',
                        checked : true,
                        group   : 'filter',
                        itemId  : 'item_code'
                      },{
                        text    : 'Description',
                        checked : false,
                        group   : 'filter',
                        itemId  : 'description'                     
                      }]              
      }]
```

how to get the which is checked from these two?

Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/ke6EZ/1/)

the idea is just add a listener to each `Ext.menu.Menu`.
if you are working with your own class, you can make `testCheck` as one of your method..

Answer (score 0):

In this case, they both can be checked or unchecked.

You can give an id to each and then simply do `Ext.getCmp('id1').getValue()` and `Ext.getCmp('id2').getValue()` to get the state of each

If you want to use these as a "group", you will have to wrap them in a [CheckboxGroup](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup) or [RadioGroup](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup) depending on your requirement.

Comment: i'm sorry.. but can you show me how to assign CheckboxGroup or RadioGroup to the item of `Ext.menu.Menu` ?? AFAIK, `menu` config at the button refer to `Ext.menu.Menu` class... and `Ext.menu.Menu` does not accept Checkboxgroup or radiogroup.